# Over 64 Client requests from WCF client rather than default 2?

Tags: wcf, concurrency, httpwebrequest, httpclient

I have a WCF Web service client program that will send over 200 concurrent requests through either WCF client proxy async calls generated by SvcUtil.exe to the service. I had presumed that CLR will honer the maxconnection=2 in the client config.

```
  <system.net>
<defaultProxy enabled="true">
  <proxy bypassonlocal="False" usesystemdefault="True" />
  <bypasslist />
  <module />
</defaultProxy>
<connectionManagement>
  <add address="*" maxconnection="2" />
</connectionManagement>
```

I know the default value of maxconnection is 2 anyway, and my codes do NOT have System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit defined. However, when I run Fiddler 2 to monitor the outbound requests, my program always sends 64 requests within 0.5 second concurrently, ignoring maxconnection.

Here's the codes:

```
    namespace DemoClient
{
    class Program
    {
        const string realWorldEndpoint = "DefaultBinding_RealWorld";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new int[100];
            for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
            {
                list[i] = i;
            }


            var tasks  = list.Select(d =>
            {
                return GetHardData(d);
            });

            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

            Console.WriteLine("All done.");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static async Task<string> GetHardData(int d)
        {
            using(    RealWorldProxy client = new RealWorldProxy(realWorldEndpoint))
            {
                client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
                client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "tttttttt";
                return await client.GetHardDataAsync(d);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

and the implementation of GetHardData in the service side is:

```
        public string GetHardData(int value)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(40000);
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
```

I understand my codes had spin off over 100 threads because of thread over-subscription intended, but I would expect them to be queued in the http connection pool which should allow only 2 outbound requests/connections by default.

This behavior may cause client timeout if the Web service is not responding fast enough to finish 64 requests each in 60 seconds, since by default the Web service hosted in IIS will limit 2 concurrent calls from the same client, so the other 62 requests have to wait, thus some of them may timeout.

Do I miss something?

Technically I may construct a thread queue or a custom TaskScheduler to limit the number of concurrent calls to 2, however, I would like to rely to the default settings of thread pool and http / tcp pools to queue.

Do I miss something? how to limit concurrent http requests of the WCF client according to maxconnection in config?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's 2 concurrent requests *per host*. Is it possible that you've got 2 slow requests to service A, but lots of *quick* requests to service B? (It's not really clear whether the fact that there are two services involve is relevant or not...)

Comment: @JonSkeet, just edited the wording. the program just runs one plugin at a time. And the Web service is a PHP program I don't have direct control, namely Magento SOAP API running on LAMP. The question is all about the behavior client, why sending 64 http requests concurrently rather than 2.

Comment: Just to check, this is lots of requests to the same host? Can you reproduce this with a small console app, to validate that it's nothing else that your code is doing?

Comment: my program is a console app. I actually had ever constructed thread pools and connection pools from scratch in a few languages over years. I am just curious of the CLR behavior, so I could be able to depend more on the default behavior. Anyway, I will try to make a simpler console app to isolated possible causes.

Comment: I had written a very simple console app and confirm that maxconnection is ignored. Just edited the question with more source codes.

Comment: Thanks. That's a much better starting point for me to try to reproduce the problem, which I'll do tonight.